# Why can we use present participles but not past participles in some reduced relative clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses, participles

Who’s the girl dancing over there? = Who's the girl (who is) dancing over there?

BUT this sentence is not possible:

Who's the girl danced with my husband? = Who's the girl (who) danced with my husband?

WHEREAS

The people invited to the party had a great time = The people (who were) invited...

is a correct sentence.

What's the logic going on here?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146150/discussion-on-question-by-chilli-why-can-we-use-present-participles-but-not-past); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

It's not logic; [logic has to do with meaning](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/logicguide.pdf). It's syntax, which has to do with sentence grammaticality (no matter what the sentence means). In the following examples, parentheses mark optional material, and asterisk marks ungrammaticality (asterisk before a parenthesis means deleting the material inside is forbidden, so (2) is ungrammatical without *who* or *that*).

> 1. *Who’s the girl (**who is**) dancing over there?*
>    (grammatical with or without *who is*)
> 2. *Who's the girl *(**who/that**) danced with my husband?*
>    (ungrammatical without relative pronoun *who* or *that*)
> 3. *The people (**who were**) invited to the party had a great time*
>    (grammatical with or without *who were*)

The reason why (1) and (3) are grammatical but (2) isn't is obvious in the parentheses above. (1) and (3) both delete a string consisting of a relative pronoun (*who* or *that* in this case) plus a form of *be* that agrees with that pronoun (*is* and *were* in this case). That's the form that the well-known English syntactic rule of [***Whiz*-Deletion**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299) requires.

And it really doesn't have anything to do with which kind of participle is used. Note that past participles are OK, **provided** they use auxiliary *be*, like the Passive construction:

4. *Who was the girl (**who/that was**) arrested for dancing in the street?*

(2), on the other hand, only deletes the relative pronoun, and **not** any auxiliary form of *be*. There is no syntactic rule that allows such deletions. So it's ungrammatical because it doesn't follow the grammatical rule, while (1) and (3) are grammatical because they **do** follow the grammatical rule. There are [a lot of grammatical rules](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13492/15299) like *Whiz*-Deletion, and they produce ungrammatical sentences when they're not applied correctly.

Comment: There's also the issue of "[her husband *recently returned from the USA* is an engineer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598626/why-is-arrived-girl-incorrect-but-recently-arrived-girl-is-correct)", which doesn't seem to involve whiz-deletion. (It does, though, if one considers the old-fashioned non-passive "to be" + past participle.)

Comment: _Her husband who is recently returned, and was recently inducted into the Academy._

Comment: Yes, so you're either using "is" + past participle (the old-fashioned way of forming certain perfect constructions) or construing "returned" as an adjective (which is perhaps possible but has its own issues).

Comment: Up-voted +1. That's so important, the difference between logic of meaning and syntax of sentence construction. Thank you.